# Can't draw a diagonal line across the window (from upper left corner to bottom right corner)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been trying for 2 days now to draw a simple diagonal line from one edge of the form's window to the other edge of it, and I just can't seem to make it work, I have tried many solutions but none of them really worked.
this is my code:
Form Setup:

```
private Bitmap drawingSurface = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            drawingSurface = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(drawingSurface.Width, drawingSurface.height);
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            //I used a PictureBox to put the drawing surface on for faster loading times
        }
```

Game Environment Setup (The diagonal line I am trying to make):

```
private void Game_Env() {
            Graphics GFX = Graphics.FromImage(drawingSurface);
            GFX.Clear(Color.Black);
            GFX.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), 0, 0, drawingSurface.Width, drawingSurface.Height);
            //this is the problomatic line of the code, the line does not strech correctly along the screen
            pictureBox1.Image = drawingSurface;
        }
```

The Game_Env function is called from the MainForm_Load function, do not worry about the details.

Here is a Picture of what the line currently looks like:
[image: as you can see, the line is not at the corner of the winforms window]

I would be really glad for any help I could get on this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you require more details to analyze my problem and understand it better, please tell me and I will edit the question and provide them.

Comment: `this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height`  Your dimensions include the borders.  You probably want the form's ClientSize property instead.

Comment: Your form width is this.Size.Width while picture box drawingSurface.Width (not equal).  Same with height.

Answer (score 1):

Solution by: LarsTech https://stackoverflow.com/users/719186/larstech
In the comments below my question.
The Solution is to use the ClientSize Property instead of the Size property, so the drawingSurface should be defined like this:

```
drawingSurface = new Bitmap(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height);
```